# SQL query to filter out match results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

```
        SELECT TOP 92 PERCENT 
        Convert(DateTime,Floor(Cast((DateTime) as Float)*24)/24,0) AS SummaryDateTime,
        MIN(APM_ApplicationAvailability.PercentAvailability) AS MIN_of_ApplicationAvailability,
        Nodes.Caption AS NodeName 

        FROM 
        (Nodes INNER JOIN APM_AlertsAndReportsData ON (Nodes.NodeID = APM_AlertsAndReportsData.NodeId))  INNER JOIN APM_ApplicationAvailability ON (APM_AlertsAndReportsData.ApplicationId = APM_ApplicationAvailability.ApplicationID)


        WHERE 
        ( DateTime BETWEEN 40907 AND 41205 )
         AND  
        (
          (APM_AlertsAndReportsData.ApplicationName LIKE '%HTTP%') AND 
          (Nodes.Caption = 'www.example.com')
        )
GROUP BY Convert(DateTime,Floor(Cast((DateTime) as Float)*24)/24,0), 
Nodes.Caption


ORDER BY SummaryDateTime ASC
```

Above query giving me following result, which attached as an image. [image]

I want to write a query to filter out all `0.00%` results so it will just gives only `0.00%` data, because i don't care about `100%` data. I don't know how to filter data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that your full query? You have mixed aggregates (`MIN`) and non-aggregates (`Datetime`).
I'll assume you have a GROUP BY somewhere, but in any case, the straightforward approach will be to subquery it.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 92 PERCENT
        Convert(DateTime,Floor(Cast((DateTime) as Float)*24)/24,0) AS SummaryDateTime,
        MIN(APM_ApplicationAvailability.PercentAvailability) AS MIN_of_ApplicationAvailability,
        Nodes.Caption AS NodeName 
    FROM Nodes
    INNER JOIN APM_AlertsAndReportsData
            ON Nodes.NodeID = APM_AlertsAndReportsData.NodeId
    INNER JOIN APM_ApplicationAvailability
            ON APM_AlertsAndReportsData.ApplicationId = APM_ApplicationAvailability.ApplicationID
    WHERE DateTime BETWEEN 40907 AND 41205
      AND APM_AlertsAndReportsData.ApplicationName LIKE '%HTTP%'
      AND Nodes.Caption = 'www.example.com'
    -- GROUP BY..
) X
WHERE MIN_of_ApplicationAvailability = 0.0
```

Normally, for aggregate queries, you can also use the HAVING clause, such as

```
    SELECT TOP 92 PERCENT
        Convert(DateTime,Floor(Cast((DateTime) as Float)*24)/24,0) AS SummaryDateTime,
        MIN(APM_ApplicationAvailability.PercentAvailability) AS MIN_of_ApplicationAvailability,
        Nodes.Caption AS NodeName 
    FROM Nodes
    INNER JOIN APM_AlertsAndReportsData
            ON Nodes.NodeID = APM_AlertsAndReportsData.NodeId
    INNER JOIN APM_ApplicationAvailability
            ON APM_AlertsAndReportsData.ApplicationId = APM_ApplicationAvailability.ApplicationID
    WHERE DateTime BETWEEN 40907 AND 41205
      AND APM_AlertsAndReportsData.ApplicationName LIKE '%HTTP%'
      AND Nodes.Caption = 'www.example.com'
    GROUP BY DateTime, Nodes.Caption
    HAVING MIN(APM_ApplicationAvailability.PercentAvailability) = 0.0
```

Comment: Just add the missing part to my answer above

Comment: You posted two query which one should i use?